# Change the size of a web page

Tags: html, resize

Actually I have done my webpage with a 800x600 monitor.
All things are well, but I encountered a problem when i explore 
the page with bigger screens.

And there are the problem with larger screens.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLNdH.jpg)

Comment: what is the question and what results are you looking to have?

Comment: an option to look into is to bootstrap your site

Comment: Thank you for quick interest. I want that the page will be displayed like is displayed in 800x600 set up (Big)

Comment: welcome; you have answers below, see those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is normal behavior for most CSS frameworks.  If font sizes and element widths, etc. are specified in pixels:  400 pixels fills up half an 800px screen but only a fraction of a 1900px screen.

That works quite well because for phones vs tablets vs desktop monitors, the highers screen resolution balances out the size of the screen, so "readable" size text will be the same number of pixels.  The difference is you can fit MORE elements on a bigger screen.  See responsive CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

If you really want your content to fill up the same amount of screen, regardless of screen size, you can define all you CSS width and height and font-size attributes as percentages of viewport size, see https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/.

Answer (score 0):

Provide width in percentage instead of pixel for responsive design. Match width in pixel and percentage and assign.

eg:
width: 10%;